# Unable to send Ctrl+V in PureRef

Tags: autohotkey

Unable to Send Ctrl+V to PureRef.

Here's the script->

```
F1::
WinActivate, ahk_class Qt5QWindowIcon ;;            Activates PureRef
Send, ^v             ;;; didn't worked
SendInput, ^v        ;;; didn't worked..
return
```

Is there something Wrong?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Could be happening too fast. Try adding some `Sleep` before the send command. If that solves the problem, try if you can get away with just a simple [`WinWaitActive` command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWaitActive.htm).

Comment: This script appears to work fine for me. Maybe make sure the contents of your clipboard are pastable items in PureRef?- that was the only scenario where it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;Try this,

F1::
IfWinExist, PureRef ; Checks If PureRef is running..
{
    WinActivate, ahk_class Qt5QWindowIcon ; Activates PureRef
    Sleep 100
    Send,{Ctrl down}
    Sleep 60
    Send,{v down}
    Sleep 60
    Send,{v up}
    Sleep 60
    Send,{Ctrl up}
    ;MsgBox done
}
return
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are some things you can do to make sure that your script runs correct.
Is your PureRef window really activating with `ahk_class Qt5QWindowIcon`?

The standard variable **%clipboard%** contains the clipboard as text.
You could also try `SendInput`, `SendRaw` and `SendPlay` to send the clipboard as text.

```
F1::
ClipWait ; Wait for the clipboard to actually contain something
IfWinExist, ahk_class Qt5QWindowIcon ; Make sure the window exists
{ 
    WinActivate ; Uses the window found by IfWinExist
    WinWaitActive ; Wait for the window to be active
    IfWinActive ; Make sure that the window is active
    {
        Send %clipboard% ; Send text-content of clipboard
    }
}
return
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this before your Send

```
A_SendMode := 'Event'
A_KeyDuration := 10
```

You could play around with `A_SendMode`, `A_KeyDelay` and `A_KeyDuration`

refs https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=93053